# Disable, Change Value, Reset a Button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a button change its value from 'Submit' to 'Loading...' AND have the button disabled while processing some code. The button should reset after the process is finished. I feel that this can be done better than individually using .attr and .prop. Can anyone help improve my code to its most efficient form?

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">Submit</button>
```

Thanks to everyone's explanation about .attr and different styles of writing, I am starting to feel that this may be the most efficient way I find to write this piece since it lessens access to '#button' so many times.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).text('Loading...').prop('disabled', true);

    //process

    $(this).text('Submit').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

from

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).attr('value', 'Loading...');

    //process

    $(this).attr('value', 'Submit');
    $(this).prop("disabled", false)
});
```

Please comment if you disagree or have a better style of writing.

Comment: Improve it in what way? What is the problem? You want, essentially, to use aliases instead, or something?

Comment: What do you want in `process`?

Comment: Well, I was thinking if it was possible to append a '.prop('disabled', true)' or '.attr('value', 'Submit')' at the end of .click(). It did not work for me so I am asking if I am doing things wrong and if it should be done another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an `<input>` with type button - it's a button, and in HTML5 buttons, the value goes inside the tags themselves, e.g. `<button>Value</button>`. Therefore, trying to manipulate it's value using jQuery's `attr` won't work as the value is the text itself.

What you need to use is jQuery's [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Here's a **[working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/g6f3z/1/)**

and the code itself:

```
$(this).text('Loading...').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very informative point I did not know about.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` or `.html()`

```
$(this).text('Loading...');
$(this).html('Loading...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).text('Loading...');

    //process

    $(this).text('Submit');
    $(this).prop("disabled", false)
});
```

Read http://api.jquery.com/text

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two like

```
$(this).html("Loading...").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: This looks sensible but for some reason my button is not being disabled.

Comment: typed disable instead of disabled in prop... just edited... try it now

Comment: I believe that this is the quickest way to do it. But .html should be replaced by .text instead.